# how to add a content creation in a view

Tags: nodes

I've created a view where it displays all created articles by the current login user. named as "my Articles".

Now, I need to add a `node/add/articles` (which let me add a new article) together with the "my Articles"(view). where the "node/add/articles" is above of "my articles".

I don't have any idea how could I add an `node/add/articles` inside a view.

I need two solutions.

One is by not using a module and the other is using a module.

Comment: What do you mean by *content creation*? Be more specific please.

Comment: adding a new node

Comment: What is your View ? a page or a block? Where of this View you need to display the node add link and block? your question is too vague

Comment: Please explain more. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be done two ways that come to mind:

1) Create the view as a block, then under the block configuration set it to show at the top of the content region and only on `node/add/article` page

2) Create the view as a page, and then using [Advanced Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) create a block for the node/add/article form to show in the content region above the View, only on the page url for the view

> Welcome to Advanced Form Block Module. With this module you can do the
>   following:
>
> 1) Create any number of blocks with a particular node edit form.
>
> 2) create any number of blocks with a particular node add form of a
>   content type.
>
> 3) Create as many blocks as you like of each kind.
>
> 4) From the content type choose which fields to display on a per block
>   basis.However required fields will be automatically displayed.
>
> 5) All forms will be saved through ajax. So multiple node forms can be
>   independently placed on a single page and worked with simultaneously.